# New to For Loops, looking for a bit of guidance

Tags: java, for-loop

The program I am writing is one that has a validation loop to see if a family has the right amount of members for a survey (3-6) about their househould mpg. If they don't i have the program setup to tell them the do no meet the requirements and must enter a different number if they would like to proceed. I understand the validation loop i think, but the next part of the `for` loop is not as easy.

I'm not sure how the program will know how many times the user should enter the different mpgs for each car in the family. For instance if one family has 3 members and the other has 5. I need a separate input box. I'm mostly confused on what i would put in the for argument. Here is my code that I have so far.

EDIT: I have what I think is the correct way to format the for loop. Now I have to figure out how to have the user input the data into the body of the for loop. So if they have 3 cars I need to have them enter the mpg for each and then calculate the average. Im stuck on how to store each cars mpgs separately.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MpgRetry
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String familyMembersStr, mpgStr;
    int familyMembers;
    int mpgAverage;



    familyMembersStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter number of family members: ");
    familyMembers=Integer.parseInt(familyMembersStr);

    while(familyMembers <3 || familyMembers >6)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, this survey can only use data from families with 3-6 members.");

        familyMembersStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the number of family members (3-6): ");

        familyMembers = Integer.parseInt(familyMembersStr);
    }

    double[] mpg = new double[familyMembers];  // creat array to hold values

    for (int i = 0; i < familyMembers; i++)
    {  // assuming each member has one car
       mpgStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter MPG each car (separately): ");
       mpg[i] = Integer.parseInt(mpgStr);

    }

        mpgAverage = (mpg / familyMembers);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The average mpg of this family is " + mpgAverage + ".");

}
```

}

Comment: What's with the downvotes?

Comment: Maybe you should first ask how many cars the family owns?

Comment: Hey Guru, I guess I didnt explain that, for the assignment each family member represents one car!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
double[] mpg = new double[familyMembers];  // creat array to hold values
for (int i = 0; i < familyMembers; i++){  // assuming each member has one car
   mpg[i] = // get mpg Input
}
```

If you wanted to do something like get the average, you could do this

```
double total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < mpg.length; i++) {
    total += mpg[i];
}

double average = total / mpg.length

System.out.println("Average mpg for each member is " + average);
```

**Edit: for if person has more than one car**

```
// You need an ArrayList to dynamically change the size of the array
// because you don't know exactly how many cars there will be total
ArrayList<Double> mpgList = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (int i = 0; i < familyMembers; i++){  
   int cars = // ...input dialog to ask how many cars each person has goes here
   for (int j = 0; j < cars; j++) {
      mpg = // user input
      mpgList.add(mpg)
   }
}

// to get total
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < mpg.size();i++){
    total += mpgList.get(i);
}

// find average here
```

**Edit: not using array**

```
double total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < familyMembers; i++){  // assuming each member has one car
    double mpg = // parsed user input
    total += mpg;  
}
// get average here
```

Comment: Hey If you happen to still be on could you chat me for a second? I think this is the right track!

Comment: I just edited the code. The last variable mpgAverage is giving me and error.

Comment: Which line are you talking about? If you want to display the average, you should use `average` instead of `familyMembers`

Comment: I should have said this above but for this assignment each member = 1 car.

Comment: You didn't get the `total`.  You need to do that with a loop. I have solution is in my code, prior to to the edit.  Then get the `average` by dividing the `total` by `familyMembers` or `mpg.length`. Either one is fine.

Comment: Just so you understand, `mpg` is an array and doesn't have a single value, so it can't be used to calculate.  You have to use the values inside the array to to calculate a `total`

Comment: And you should use `Doublde.parseDouble(mpgStr)` instead of `Integer` because you're putting a `double` value into the array, not an `int`.

Comment: Yea of course you've been so helpful. I honestly have not learned some of the stuff you have been showing me, so hopefully I will be soon. Is there any way to friend people on this site?

Comment: Not that I know of. But I'm on alot.  Also, If you haven't learned about arrays, I really don't suggest you turn your work in like this.  There are ways to do it with out arrays, it just takes a lot more code.

Comment: See my bottom edit.  Now that I think about it, you really don't need an array for this problem.  You can just do it the way I have in the edit.

Comment: Hey Skillet I just made a new post about an assignment that I have that is pretty similar to this. There is something about the for loop concept that is challenging to me. Anyway if you happen to see this would you mind giving it a look?

Comment: Most of the people on this site are very competent. I'm sure you'll get some good help from others.  What's the link, I'll check it out in case you haven't gotten any good help yet

Answer (score 0):

so I think your second loop should be an if statement
so your second statement would look like

```
if(familyMembers >= 3 && familyMembers <= 6)
{
}
```

As far as what you should do in that statement
I would create a counter at the top of your program,

```
int currentCar = 1;
```

then in the if statement you could have a while loop like

```
while(currentCar !> familyMembers)
{
}
```

and basically in that while loop you would ask them to input the mpg for "current car," store that and then increment currentCar.

Comment: Our teacher is requiring us to use a FOR loop for valid inputs. As for storing data, I have not gotten far enough in class to do that yet.

Answer (score 0):

Say if the there are 4 family members...

What do you want to do with these family members? if you want to loop as many as the number of family members you can simply use this kind of for loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<familyMembers; i++){
     //some code
}
```

Comment: So once the validation loop is done it will ask for the user to input the mpg for each car in the family. So if the person put in 3 cars to get past the validation loop then in the for loop I need 3 seperate input boxes one after the other so that the user can enter the mpgs in. Then once they have done this I will have it calculate the average and a message dialog will be displayed.